# How can i map a POJO to a directory with ApacheDs?

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, ldap, persistence

i have downloaded ApacheDS as my LDAP server, now i am trying to map a pojo to a directory, is there any ODM (Object Directory Mapper) out there? i mean something like Hibernate but for LDAP. 
i have found s2Directory and LDAP-ODM, but the tutorial and user support on these seems not to be sophisticated. so do you know anything for this purpose? 
thnx

Answer (score 0):

The UnboundID LDAP SDK for java provides a relatively simple persistence framework for use with LDAP directories.

Comment: hmm, let me take a look at it, does it support ApacheDS? have you used it for yourself?

Comment: It should work with any LDAP-compliant directory server.  I wrote the code, so if you encounter any problems, you can use one of the mailing lists or the discussion forum.